# How to handle 500 error in Kotlin and show detail message using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I use the next references to implement retrofit on kotlin solution

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1'
```

I implement an api it return this result:

[image]

Postman test is ok.

With the basic callback retrofit i intercept the result code + message http

```
if (response.code() == 500) {
     val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create()

     var locerr = gson.fromJson(response?.errorBody()?.string(),
                                           err::class.java)
     Log.e("MainActivity", "${locerr.code} => ${locerr.message}")
```

But i dont't see the "result" this value is not in errorbody or body because it s not successful case (200)

How can i get result or handle error "result" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this-->

```
            if (res.body()?.status==200) {
                 .
                 .
                    }

            else
                    {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                                JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                            jObjError.getString("yout_message_key"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                        }
                    }
```